# Stop in runtime. (Check update android app)

Tags: java, android, database, runtime-error, auto-update

Who can help me? It stopped working at runtime.

```
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Map map = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            String version = String.valueOf(map.get("Version"));
            String url_update = String.valueOf(map.get("Update_URL"));
            setting.edit().putString("url_update", url_update);
            if (your_version != version) {
                Dialog_update.setMessage("คุณมีการอัพเดทใหม่"); //This Thai Language. I use it on message.
                Dialog_update.setNegativeButton("ตกลง", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface _dialog, int _which ) {
                        outurl.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        outurl.setData(Uri.parse(setting.getString("url_update", "")));
                        startActivity(outurl);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

I test it by change "version" in realtime database on console.

Comment: Post your logcat, to have a chance to get any help.

Comment: Search "how to compare strings in java"